# Socket.io doesn't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

i have a problem with socket.io(node.js):
I have a starting script called serverNode.js. 
The script is working in other computers but
when i try to run it in my computer it just doesn't do nothing.

**Working code**

```
C:\Users\User>cd c:\nodejs

c:\nodejs>node serverNode.js
   info  - socket.io started
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized C9uBAi24armt4EdA91hS
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/C9uBAi24armt4EdA91hS
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client C9uBAi24armt4EdA91hS
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - client authorized
```

**Code running in my computer**

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

C:\Users\amorillas>cd c:/nodejs

c:\nodejs>node serverNode.js
_
```

Thanks in advance and i hope you can help me :)

Comment: Did you run `npm install socket.io`?

Comment: yes, i did. It shows an error if you dont install socket.io. But it doesn't show nothing.

Comment: can you show the `serverNode.js` contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script does start normally. You don't see any log messages because since socket.io 1.0 logging is disabled by default.

From the [official docs](http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/):

> Before 1.0, the Socket.IO server would default to logging everything out to the console. This turned out to be annoyingly verbose for many users (although extremely useful for others), so now we default to being completely silent by default.

You just have different versions of socket.io on your computers.

Comment: Thanks. You are right! node js is working but it doesn't show nothing, so i thought it didn't work. Thank you again :)

Answer (score -3):

Try nodejs serverMode.js instead of node serverNode.js i will work

Comment: ok  but what happen when you type node server.js command  please show full output 
If you have install two different version of nodejs thats why this problem you have faced.

So please try to reinstall nodejs for your appropriate 32 or 62 bit windows machine.